# Select TOP 1 in SQL Server 6.5

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-6.5

I beg you don't ask me why am I using SQL Server 6.5

There is no SELECT TOP command in SQL Server 6.5, and guess what, I need it :)

I need to perform something like

```
Select top 1 * from persons
where name ='Mike'
order by id desc
```

I've tried something with SET ROWCOUNT 1, but in that case you cannot use order by.

I end up with

```
Select top 1 * from persons
where id = (select max(id) from persons where name ='Mike' )
```

There must be better way!

Any suggestions?

Thanx!

Comment: I feel your pain, but I think you are stuck with wierd quirky syntax.

Comment: And here I was just complaining about being stuck in MS SQL 2000.  Guess I'll shut up now :)

Answer (score 2):

Try selecting into a temporary table, ordered by ID, then SET ROWCOUNT 1 and select * from temporary table. (This should work for any top N with SET ROWCOUNT N, while your existing solution will only work for top 1.)

Comment: I need only top 1, so I'm fine with it. But what is more expensive, nested select or temp table?

Comment: @100r, I think the correct answer to that is "it depends". The only way to be certain would be to try running both and see how they compare.

Answer (score 0):

SET ROWCOUNT 1 before your select statement, haven't tested this as I do not have mssql 6.5 (lucky I guess)

Comment: tried that but you cannot use order by when setting rowcount :/

Comment: I wonder if you could do a rowcount, and inside have a select with your order